# Why can't I write to object property with index type inference

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, mapped-types

I have this function

```
function foo<T extends { [P in K]: number }, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): void {
  const x: number = obj[key]
  obj[key] = 123 //error
}
```

`obj[key]` has type `number`
but I cannot write number to it

> Type '123' is not assignable to type 'T[K]'.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is working as intended. Imagine you invoke `foo` like this:

```
const obj = {a: 42} as const
foo(obj,"a") 
// foo<{readonly a: 42; }, "a">(obj: { readonly a: 42; }, key: "a"): void
```

Then `T[K]` won't be `number`, but `42` (a subtype) - an assignment of `123` to `a` wouldn't be valid anymore. Inside `foo` body, we only know for sure, that `T[K]` is some kind of `number` (generic constraint of `T`), but not what the *exact* type is.

Hence TS will emit the error `Type '123' is not assignable to type 'T[K]'` - the compiler cannot ensure, that `123` is the right type, as generic types are set by the *caller* of `foo`. The only type that can be checked statically is `T[K]`.

To write `number` to certain properties `K`, you can change the signature as follows:

```
function foo<K extends PropertyKey>(obj: Record<K, number>, key: K): void {
  const x: number = obj[key]
  obj[key] = 123 
}

const obj = { foo: 1, bar: true }
foo(obj, 'foo') // works
```

[TS Playground sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=16&pln=6&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8BpRBTAHlbMAEwGdEAFAJzgAdtKoBPDbRgPgAo4AjAKwC5EAJWwQ4lIpgA0iMCAC23emxkBrVoIwBKQQDc4MIogDeAWABQiRGLAkoiXILmL6iALyIevANrrGAXQsrL19Wf3dEAEYAJgBmCwBfCwsbO08%20CONkVEFImW4AQ0pBKEoQbEQk8xQ4Lj4ZAHIahq0gA)

Comment: I want to use this function with any object `foo({foo: 1, bar: boolean}, 'foo')` so number to all properties wouldn't work for me

Comment: There are two possibilities: If you want to invoke `foo` directly with an object literal argument, there is no reason to specify anything other than `number` properties, as `foo` can only deal with `numbers`. The other case is some existent object, which you just pass to `foo`. The latter already works, as no excess property checks are done here by the compiler - have a look at the updated answer.